# are all homomorphic groups of the same size isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I came across this question while working on a problem from my practice final for abstract algebra.

[image]

I've set up the groups, and proved the homomorphism, and shown that the two groups have the same order.  So can I state that all homomorphic groups of the same order are isomorphic?

Here's what [I have](https://www.dropbox.com/s/esph5flumobachl/PracFinal9.png?dl=0) so far.

Comment: What are "homomorphic" groups??

Comment: You can't "prove a homomorphism". What you can do is find one and then prove that it is a bijection. Then it is an isomorphism.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own questions, Dana. It can help if you share your proofs here so we can give feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a trivial counter-example.

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups of the same order, but not isomorphic. For any pair of groups, there is always the $0$ homomorphism between them, i.e. the map $0: G \to H: G \ni g \mapsto e \in H$. This is a homomorphism trivially, and so there is a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$, but somehow it is not a useful homomorphism. It's not even close to an isomorphism.

I expect the relationship you're after is given by the First Isomorphism Theorem, which in a sense tells you how a homomorphism can be 'close' to an isommorphism. In particular, if $\phi: G \to H$ is a homomorphism, this theorem asserts that $G/\ker \phi \simeq H$.

Edit: If by homomorphic you mean that $G$ has a homomorphic image which is ONTO $H$, then yes your claim is true, since for groups with the same finite order, being surjective implies being injective.

Comment: The two groups are clearly one to one and onto, but I hate proofs that say "clearly" I've come across too many where I erupt with "ITS NOT CLEAR TO ME!"  But the walls of my room care not.  LOL

Comment: @DanaHill groups cannot be bijective. Do you mean that there is a bijective map between them? In this case it's an isomorphism by definition.

Comment: Language and terminology are important.  (*I keep telling myself that.  I used to drill it into the heads of stubborn high schoolers*)

Yes.  According to the map I used, they have a bijection.  I was just trying to show that without using the terms "clearly" or "obviously".